# Many small images in one UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have 4 different images which should be scaled to 5px*7.5px each and then added to UIScrollView 320x480 randomly. That's 64x64=4096 images in one view. A lot of images. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You'd better paint them directly on your parent view, using `[UIImage drawInRect:]` in your view's `drawRect`. Otherwise, having 4,096 subviews in the parent view could lead to huge performance drops.

Comment: I agree with Cyrille. Performance-wise this would surely be a much better solution.

Comment: Depends if you need to animate them independently, for example. In this case you'd need a reference to each of them. But even in this case, you'd be better off adding CALayers to your parent view’s layer, rather that UIImageView-subviews to your parent view.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you name images `img0.png, img1.png, img2.png, img3.png`.

You could use a code like this:

```
for (int x=0;x<64;x++) {
    for (int y=0;y<64;x++) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d.png", arc4random()%3]]];
        CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = x*5.0;
        frame.origin.y = y*7.5;
        imgView.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView.view addSubView: imgView];
    }
}
```

Comment: If however you go for this subviews solution, please at least disable autoresizing options on all your little subviews. It will save a lot of drawing time.

Comment: I tried that way, but it takes too much time to render. Can you post some example for [UIImage drawInRect:] solution?

Comment: Using random function in drawRect will cause background to change each time it is redrawn. If this is what you want i can write you a short snippet how to do it. If this is not what you want then things become a bit more complex but also viable. Please explain exactly what kind of behaviour is needed.

Comment: I have one big image 320x480 and on user tap I want to show 64x64 small images over that image.

Comment: Ok - would you later need to know which of the 4 different images is at certain place?

Comment: Yes, the images will be placed by average color. Image average color and average color in area of the main image.